# Handling error in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

1) How can I handle "server error" and "page not found" **on the application level**? Where should I put a handler which renders appropriate pages?

That is, if a user goes to "my_website.com/fdafdsafds" -- how can I render the page "error/my_custom_404_page.html" to him?

Or if somewhere in my app an error occurs such as "1 / 0", how can I catch it on the application level?

2) Inside a plug I have this:

```
  def call(conn, opts) do
    if !some_condition do
      # ....
    else
      # how to render an html template?
      Conn.send_resp(conn, 401, "access denied") |> Conn.halt()
    end
  end
```

How can I render my custom error html template from "error/my_html_template.html" and pass parameters to it?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** You are to declare custom exceptions (with standard Elixir `defexception` macro) and to implement [`Plug.Exception`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Exception.html#content) protocol for them, like this:

```
defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.NoResultsError do
  def status(_exception), do: 418
end
```

Then, once raised, it will be handled by this implementation.

---

There is a detailed description on how to do this in [Phoenix](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/errors.html#content) documentation. I do not see any reason to copy the content from there, but I must admit the explanation is pretty straightforward.

Comment: that's only 1) How about 2)?

Comment: No, this answers both questions: throw a custom exception from your `Plug` instead of explicit `Conn.halt()`.

Comment: throwing an exception is costly compared to rendering an error template instead. is there a way to render an error template?

Comment: and also, how can re-define this `def render("404.html", _assigns) do` to something like `def render("404_not_found.html", _assigns) do`? For me "404" doesn't mean anything, but "404_not_found" -- does.

Comment: “throwing an exception is costly compared to rendering an error template instead”—do you have any proof of that? Also, if you want to render smth, just render it with [`render(conn, "template.html")`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#rendering-templates).

Comment: `Also, if you want to render smth, just render it with render(conn, "template.html")` -- my question is "how to render it from a Plug", not from a controller. P.S. -- I think I've found a way, I'll check

Comment: **do you have any proof of that?** --> google `elixir exception costly overhead`

Comment: `render` just produces a string, that is to be sent to the client as the third parameter of the call to `Plug.Conn.send_resp/3`. It does not matter where to call it from. You might be interested in reading [`Plug.ErrorHandler`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.ErrorHandler.html#content) docs as well. Also, “google for ...” is not a proof of anything. This should be considered a perfect example of premature optimisation.

Comment: how can re-define this `ErrorView#def render("404.html", _assigns)` do to something like `ErrorView#def render("404_not_found.html", _assigns)` do? For me "404" doesn't mean anything, but "404_not_found" -- does.

Comment: also, just "render" doesn't work -- it throws an exception. render_to_string renders html as a string. that is, none of the solutions you've suggested work.

Answer (score -1):

> 1) How can I handle "server error" and "page not found" on the
>   application level? Where should I put a handler which renders
>   appropriate pages?

I used following trick

```
scope "/", MyApp do  
  post "/*path",  PageController, :invalid_path  
  put "/*path",  PageController, :invalid_path  
  get "/*path",  PageController, :invalid_path  
end
```

And define custom error message in **invalid_path** method.

**NOTE: Add these lines at end of the router file**

Comment: Please do not do this; check my answer, it contains a link to Phoenix documentation, that has a detailed description on how to do this in a proper way.

Comment: This is a bad pattern and shouldn't be used.